# The difference between : 日 vs 号

Tags: usage, difference

I was reading a conversation and came to these sentences :

> 爸爸 ：双十一是什么？
>
> 妈妈 ：就是11月11号的网上购物节，在网上买东西很便宜。

I was wondering why it's 号 instead of 日. I then checked it on the dictionary and found out that 号 can mean "the day of the month".

I have looked for an answer but not sure whether or not what I found is correct. It's said that 日 is more formal than 号 and that 号 is used when you speak casually.
Is that true? And is there any more difference between both words?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, what you said is correct for your context.

Comment: **X 号** originally means **Number X**, but still used for day of month in spoken language, **X 日** is used in written language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, 日 is more formal than 号。

When chatting with someone, you would normally use 号 instead of 日，in this case, saying 日 feels a little bit weird.

But when you are writing a document, you would want to use 日 unless you are writing a transcript of people chatting with each other.

Answer (score 1):

日：day；号：the rank number

11号：the 11th day of the month. But Chinese prefer a concise expression, just 11th,that is 11号

Answer (score 1):

在表达日期时候，日和号是同样的意思。但其他情况不一定。日通常表示day, 号通常表示number

Answer (score 1):

If you're specifically talking about mentioning dates, then you have understood this correctly. I have never seen 号 on my work documents or when I was signing contracts in China. I see 年——月——日 every time instead. In colloquial speech, 号 is used.

Answer (score 0):

如果表示日期的时候既有月又有日，比如

> 11月11日， 11月11号

没什么区别。

如果只说日，不带月，应该用号，比如

> 我5号的时候有个会议。

如果这里用5日，不自然。